# Copying python virtualenv in multistage docker build

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

I tried to follow [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/) guide to install packages on a venv on one step of a docker build, and copy the already built virtualenv to the second step.
The dockerfile I used:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye AS venv-image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc
COPY poetry.toml poetry.lock pyproject.toml entrypoint.sh ./
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/.venv
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
RUN pip install poetry && poetry install

FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye as app-image
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
COPY --from=venv-image /.venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I built only the venv-image everything works correctly in that container.

But when I connect to the built app-image container, I can see the venv directory, it looks correct, and when I enter python shell I can import packages successfully. However when I'm outside of the shell and run something like pip freeze it prints nothing.

The main problem is that I can't run stuff like Daphne server easily, but I'm also curious why does the venv activation doesn't work as expected.